# Multiline curly braces

Tags: math-mode, matrices, braces

I know how to draw the following multiline matrix using brackets on both sides:

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-3\\-2&-13&8\\3&-3&1\end{bmatrix}$$
```

The question is, how do I do it with curly braces? I know how to do curly braces on the left side (using `cases`), but how do I get the curly braces on both sides? I'm writing this in the Jupyter notebook version 5.7.8.

Comment: [Don't use `$$`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/203621)

Comment: So how do I do in-line math-mode (equivalent to `$`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Bmatrix` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
   \begin{Bmatrix} 
      1 &   5 & -3 \\
     -2 & -13 &  8 \\
      3 &  -3 &  1
   \end{Bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Anothers possibility on the off-chance that something was going wrong during compilation is to use `nicematrix` or `spalign` package where you can easily align minus sign easily: option `l` left, `c` center and `r` right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{BNiceMatrix}
  1 & 5 & -3 \\
 -2 & -13 &  8 \\
  3 & -3 &  1
\end{BNiceMatrix} \quad \verb|with nicematrix package|\]
\[\spaligndelims \{\} \spalignmat[r]{1 5 -3; -2 -13 8; 3 -3  1} \quad \verb|with spalign package|\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: an upvote for sharing about the package `spalign`,

Comment: @MadyYuvi Ahahaha :-) for me it is important to help the others....and that exists the sincerity and the semplicity from the people..like you.

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, the `Bmatrix` environment from `amsmath` is probably the best solution here, but I think it's worth to keep in mind that a similar result can be achieved by adding `\left\{...\right\}` around a `matrix` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}1&5&-3\\-2&-13&8\\3&-3&1\end{Bmatrix}
\qquad
\left\{ \begin{matrix}1&5&-3\\-2&-13&8\\3&-3&1\end{matrix} \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]
This solution can easily be adapted for any kind of braces, or with different braces on both sides, or even to give the matrix a brace on only one side.